# Make a Prompt box create an alert

Tags: javascript, alert, prompt

I'm trying to create a form using Javascript.

I need name and age in the form.Once fields are typed you click submit.  the submit needs to create a prompt that has you type in new background color.

Once you click ok I need an alert that says (Name from field name "Your favorite color was applied to the background of the page" "Your age is(display age from age field)

Example:  Brad your favorite color was applied to the background of the page.
Your age is 33. I can't figure out how to get the javascript to grab the name and age that has been inputted in the name and age field.

HTML code:

```
    <form>
       First name:<br>
          <input type="text" name="firstname" id="name"><br>
      Age:<br>
         <input type="text" name="txtage" id="age"><br>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="process" onclick="MyFunction">
    </form>
```

External Java Script:

```
function MyFunction() {
  x = prompt("Enter the color you want on the Background???");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = x; 
  if (x != null){       
    alert("(need name from form)Your favorite color was applied to the background of the page, your age is (need age from form) ");
  }
}
```

Comment: there is no age or name field in the java **script** code you posted - please post relevant code, rather than  working snippet

Comment: The form is written in HTML I have a name field and an age field. The name field has an ID=Name and the age field has ID=Age the submit button has an ID=process. the provided code prompts a box to pop up once submit button is clicked. You type in color you like and background changes to color you pick. What I need is to have the alert box that pops up after you click OK on the prompt box to say.  "(Name from Name field) your favorite color has been selected, your age is (Age from Age field)" I'm a new student having trouble on the startup into Java.

Answer (score 1):

One way to grab your `<input>` element from the DOM is to use its id with [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). The way to grab inputed text from this `<input>` is from its `.value` property.

Hence, to get the string text from the input with id `name`, you would do

```
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
```

Here's how that might look:

```
function MyFunction() {
  x = prompt("Enter the color you want on the Background???");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = x; 

  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var age = // ...get the age in a similar manner

  if (x != null) {       
    // concat strings using the + operator
    alert(name + "Your favorite color was applied to the background of the page, your age is " + age);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. But how do you get a space between the inputs? When the Java runs the alert comes up "Bradyour favorite color was applied to the background of the page. Your age is33" The name element and the age element won't space from the text.